# Parsing integer from Swift to SQL with JSON

Tags: php, json, swift, parsing

I'm developing an app in Swift 3 where I need to pass an integer value from the app to an online SQL server.

My Swift code is as following:

```
func saveData(data: Int) {
    // prepare json data
    let json: [String: Any] = ["matchScore": ["\(data)"]]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    // create post request
    let url = URL(string: "http://mywebpage.com/swift/addToSQL.php")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And the part of the PHP file where I'm supposed to get the JSON data:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$matchScore = $json['matchScore'][1];
```

However, the database is not getting anything. I found out that if I set $matchScore = 42 (example) it works and posts to SQL database, so it has to be the parsing that's the issue.

What am I missing out here?
Thanks.

Comment: if the `data` is a single `Int` then you need `[0]` array value, not `[1]`

Comment: Ofcourse! Man, I must be in serious lack of coffee. Thank you so much, Cyborg! Works like a charm.